# Show List of objects in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have the following class:

```
class Cliente
{
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public String nombre { get; set; }
    public String apellidos { get; set; }
    public String dni { get; set; }
    public String telefono { get; set; }
    public String movil { get; set; }
    public String direccion { get; set; }
    public String localidad { get; set; }
    public Provincia provincia { get; set; }

    public Cliente()
    {
        this.provincia = new Provincia();
    }
}
```

I have a List of this class:

```
List<Cliente> listaClientes = new List<Cliente>();
listaClientes = gestorCliente.getClientesList();
```

Ok, and now, I want to show this list in my datagrid view. But I have one problem. My "Cliente" class has a "Provincia" object. I need show in the data gridview the "description" atribute  in provincia class.

How can I do it?

- Using dataset?
- Using interface?

What is the better way to do it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can bind it using LINQ [select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = listaClientes.Select(c => new {c.idCliente, c.provincia.Description}).ToList();
```

Obviously put which attributes you wish to display into the code.

Comment: No problem. Just consider you can use a pass through property on the base class, so you don't need to access a sub class property. Such as  `public string ProvinciaDesc
        {
            get { return provincia.Description; }
            set { provincia.Description= value; }
        }`